# How to split out work from a git branch?

Tags: git, split

Sometimes working in a branch you end up getting more than you had planned for, and realize it's worth splitting out some of what you've done into another branch.

E.g. when fixing a bug that got in your way, or adding documentation, or making some small feature fix you noticed on the way.

What is the easiest way to split out some of the work you have done into a new branch?

Answer (score 0):

Use `checkout -i` to interactively select bits you want into a new branch, commit that, then use `git revert` on the large branch to remove what you split out.

E.g.

```
---A         - @{upstream}
    \
     \--B--C - LargeBranch
```

Create a new branch `SplitBranch`, off the same upstream branch LargeBranch is based on, and interactively select the changes you want there:

```
git checkout -b SplitBranch @{upstream}
git checkout -i LargeBranch
git commit
```

Resulting in:

```
---A         - @{upstream}
   |\
   | \--B--C - LargeBranch
    \
     \--D    - SplitBranch
```

Then, easily remove what you have split out into `SplitBranch` by using `git revert`:

```
git checkout LargeBranch
git revert halfFoo

---A            - @{upstream}
   |\
   | \--B--C--E - LargeBranch,  E is inverse of D.
    \
     \--D       - SplitBranch
```

Now, `LargeBranch` no longer has the content you moved into `SplitBranch`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a new branch to receive the "too much" changes at some convenient point before the mess, `git cherry-pick` the commits from the original to it, and then `git rebase -i` them out of the original. You might split some of the commits before the cherry picking.

To make sure nothing gets lost, start with a `git branch save` at the HEAD, that way you can mess around with the existing branches; blow all away and start over.